# jQuery: add Prev and Next to tabs

Tags: jquery

I am trying add Prev and Next functionality to my "tabs" but something not working.

Here is the html:

```
<a href="#" class="next-tab">next</a>
<a href="#" class="prev-tab">prev</a>

<div class="tabs">

<a href="#" class="tab new-messages">
<a href="#" class="tab statistics active">
<a href="#" class="tab shop">

</div>
```

one of the "tab" start with "active" class so when the user click on the "next",

the next "tab" will get the "active" class and this class will be removed from the Prev tab.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.next-tab').click(function () {
     if( $('.tab').hasClass("active")) {
       var tab = $('.tab').find("a.active");
       $(tab).parent().next().children().addClass("active");
       $(tab).removeClass("active");
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.tab` and `.active` elements are the same thing (the links) at the same level in the DOM so `parent()` and `find()` aren't useful here, as these look up and down the DOM tree.

You just need to get the current `.active` tab, use `prev()` or `next()` to get the element next to it, then swap the classes if one is found:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.next-tab').click(function () {
        // get current tab
        var currentTab = $(".tab.active");
        // get the next tab, if there is one (i.e. we are not at the end)
        var newTab = currentTab.next();
        if(newTab.length > 0) {
            // remove active from old tab
            currentTab.removeClass('active');
            // add active to new tab
            newTab.addClass('active');
        }
    });
    
    $('.prev-tab').click(function () {
        var currentTab = $(".tab.active");
        var newTab = currentTab.prev();
        if(newTab.length > 0) {
            currentTab.removeClass('active');
            newTab.addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="next-tab">next</a>
<a href="#" class="prev-tab">prev</a>

<div class="tabs">

    <a href="#" class="tab new-messages">Messages</a>
    <a href="#" class="tab statistics active">Stats</a>
    <a href="#" class="tab shop">Shop</a>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**: To go in a loop, you check `if(newTab.length == 0)` instead which means you are at the start or end, and then use [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) and [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) to loop to the other end:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.next-tab').click(function() {
    // get current tab
    var currentTab = $(".tab.active");

    // get the next tab, if there is one
    var newTab = currentTab.next();

    // at the end, so go to the first one
    if (newTab.length === 0) {
      newTab = $(".tab").first();
    }

    currentTab.removeClass('active');
    // add active to new tab
    newTab.addClass('active');
  });

  $('.prev-tab').click(function() {
    // get current tab
    var currentTab = $(".tab.active");

    // get the previous tab, if there is one
    var newTab = currentTab.prev();

    // at the start, so go to the last one
    if (newTab.length === 0) {
      newTab = $(".tab").last();
    }

    currentTab.removeClass('active');
    // add active to new tab
    newTab.addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="next-tab">next</a>
<a href="#" class="prev-tab">prev</a>

<div class="tabs">

  <a href="#" class="tab new-messages">Messages</a>
  <a href="#" class="tab statistics active">Stats</a>
  <a href="#" class="tab shop">Shop</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Rhumborl Thanks. how can we improve this code so when we click on the "next" or "prev" it will go on circle(loop)?