# Next and previous button functionality is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have created tab content with next and previous button functionality. But next and previous button functionality is not working. I have used jquery.min.js version 1.11.1 version. I have created snippet as below.  I have referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219404/jquery-add-prev-and-next-to-tabs)  and created functionality as mentioned in answer. but still its not working.

```js
$("ul.kyc-tab-list li a").click(function () {
        $("ul.kyc-tab-list li a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $(".tab-btn1").click(function () {
        $("#tab1").show();
        $("#tab2").hide();
        $("#tab3").hide();
        $("#tab4").hide();
        $("#tab5").hide();
    });

    $(".tab-btn2").click(function () {
        $("#tab1").hide();
        $("#tab2").show();
        $("#tab3").hide();
        $("#tab4").hide();
        $("#tab5").hide();
    });

    $(".tab-btn3").click(function () {
        $("#tab1").hide();
        $("#tab2").hide();
        $("#tab3").show();
        $("#tab4").hide();
        $("#tab5").hide();
    });

    $(".tab-btn4").click(function () {
        $("#tab1").hide();
        $("#tab2").hide();
        $("#tab3").hide();
        $("#tab4").show();
        $("#tab5").hide();
    });

    $(".tab-btn5").click(function () {
        $("#tab1").hide();
        $("#tab2").hide();
        $("#tab3").hide();
        $("#tab4").hide();
        $("#tab5").show();
    });
    
    
    $('#btnNext').click(function () {


        // get current tab

        var currentTab = $(".tab.active");

        // get the next tab, if there is one
        var newTab = currentTab.next();

        // at the end, so go to the first one
        if (newTab.length === 0) {
            newTab = $(".tab").first();
        }

        currentTab.removeClass('active');
        // add active to new tab
        newTab.addClass('active');
    });

    $('#btnPrevious').click(function () {
        // get current tab
        var currentTab = $(".tab.active");

        // get the previous tab, if there is one
        var newTab = currentTab.prev();

        // at the start, so go to the last one
        if (newTab.length === 0) {
            newTab = $(".tab").last();
        }

        currentTab.removeClass('active');
        // add active to new tab
        newTab.addClass('active');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<section>

  <div class="kyc-tab-wrapper">
                      <ul class="kyc-tab-list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab active tab-btn1"><span>01</span>Customer</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab tab-btn2"><span>02</span>Contact / Promotors</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab tab-btn3"><span>03</span>Bank / Business</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab tab-btn4"><span>04</span>Other</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab tab-btn5"><span>05</span>Finish</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    
                       <div class="kyc-tab-content" id="tab1">
                       
                       tab 1
                       </div>
                                <div class="kyc-tab-content" id="tab2">
                        tab 2
                       </div>         
                                </div>
                                
                                     <div class="kyc-tab-content" id="tab3">
                                         tab 3
                       
                                     </div>
                                                  <div class="kyc-tab-content" id="tab4">
                                                  tab 4
                                                  </div>
                                                       <div class="kyc-tab-content" id="tab5">
                                   
                                   tab 5</div>
                                                       
                                                         <div class="kyc-tab-form-btn-wrap">
                        <button id="btnPrevious" style="display:none">  Previous</button> 
                        <button id="btnNext">Next </button>
                    </div>
                       </div>
  </div>
</section>


</div>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So these are the change I've made to your code:

1. First of all, the closing tag of `kyc-tab-wrapper` was closed *after* `tab2` - fixed that.
2. Instead of having multiple listeners to switch the tabs, you can include this in the first listener itself:

   ```
   $(".kyc-tab-content").hide();
   $($(this).attr('class').split(' ').find(function(e) {
       return e.startsWith('tab-btn');
   }).replace('tab-btn', '#tab')).show();
   ```
3. The *next* and *previous* buttons are not working as you are doing `prev` and `next` on `a` - you should be doing it with `li` as `li`s are the siblings:

   ```
   currentTab.closest('li').prev().find('a');
   currentTab.closest('li').next().find('a');
   ```
4. You can just *trigger* click on the tab instead of doing the login again.
5. Also adding an *initial* trigger to show the first tab when page loads using `$(".tab.active").trigger('click')`

See demo below:

```js
$("ul.kyc-tab-list li a").click(function() {
  $("ul.kyc-tab-list li a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  /* Do this instead of multiple listeners */
  $(".kyc-tab-content").hide();
  $($(this).attr('class').split(' ').find(function(e) {
    return e.startsWith('tab-btn');
  }).replace('tab-btn', '#tab')).show();
});

// active tab load initially
$(".tab.active").trigger('click');


$('#btnNext').click(function() {
  var currentTab = $(".tab.active");
  var newTab = currentTab.closest('li').next().find('a');
  if (newTab.length === 0) {
    newTab = $(".tab").first();
  }
  newTab.trigger('click');
});

$('#btnPrevious').click(function() {
  var currentTab = $(".tab.active");
  var newTab = currentTab.closest('li').prev().find('a');
  if (newTab.length === 0) {
    newTab = $(".tab").last();
  }
  newTab.trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <section>
    <div class="kyc-tab-wrapper">
      <ul class="kyc-tab-list">
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab active tab-btn1"><span>01</span>Customer</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab tab-btn2"><span>02</span>Contact / Promotors</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab tab-btn3"><span>03</span>Bank / Business</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab tab-btn4"><span>04</span>Other</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab tab-btn5"><span>05</span>Finish</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="kyc-tab-content" id="tab1">tab 1</div>
      <div class="kyc-tab-content" id="tab2">tab 2</div>
      <div class="kyc-tab-content" id="tab3">tab 3</div>
      <div class="kyc-tab-content" id="tab4">tab 4</div>
      <div class="kyc-tab-content" id="tab5">tab 5</div>
      <div class="kyc-tab-form-btn-wrap">
        <button id="btnPrevious">  Previous</button>
        <button id="btnNext">Next </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For `Next` button to work change the following lines like below.

```
// get current tab
var currentTab = $(".tab.active").closest("li");
//get the next tab, if there is one
var newTab = currentTab.next().find("a.tab");
//...
currentTab.find(".tab").removeClass('active');
```

Do the similar changes for `Prev` button also.

```
// get current tab
var currentTab = $(".tab.active").closest("li");
// get the previous tab, if there is one
var newTab = currentTab.prev().find("a.tab");
//...
currentTab.find(".tab").removeClass('active');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/koqneL4f/)**

The issue in your code is you are not focusing the next or previous `a` tag properly.